# Application, Helper Tool Communication

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm working on a OS X desktop application. I want to bundle a helper tool with it. I was thinking of using `SMJobSubmit` to start a helper program with elevated privileges. (The tool basically does a `sudo` call.)

How could I send the console output from the tool back to my main application?

I know with `NSTask` I could use `NSPipe` to redirect console output. But, since I don't think I can use `NSTask` with elevated privileges, I'm using `SMJobSubmit` instead.

(Yes, I've taken care of the authorization part.)

Comment: Yes, it is. I should have specified that, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

I think, as far as I know, you should use XPC connection to communicate with your helper program. Instead of using SMJobSubmit(Since it is deprecated anyway) use SMJobBless to install your helper tool as a LaunchD job which runs in elevated privileges. Use XPC connection from your Mac OS X app to communicate with it to invoke the function call that executes your logic, capture the output and reply back to the main app. If you are willing to go ahead with this idea, the below sample code from Apple will guide you through.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample/Listings/Read_Me_About_EvenBetterAuthorizationSample_txt.html

Comment: This question is nearly 3 years old. So the OP is unlikely to be able to try your suggestion. Even so, the correct way to answer this would be to show the code and explanation here. If that link dies, it will then be useless to future SO users. See the [How to answer page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) for help in improving your future answers.