# How do I give this shell command in Swift 5 administrator privileges?

Tags: swift, xcode, shell, swift5, youtube-dl

I'm trying to make a GUI for the YouTube-dl tool.
(YouTube-dl.org)
I'm using this Shell function to run the necessary commands:

```
func shell(_ command: String) -> String {
    let task = Process()
    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.arguments = ["-c", command]
    task.launchPath = "/bin/bash"
    task.launch()
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
    return output
```

This is the code I wrote to launch YouTube-dl when a button is press, give it a YouTube URL and save the downloaded video to the desktop:

```
 @IBAction func actionMP4(_ sender: Any) {
        
    shell("/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl -o ~/Desktop/DownloadedVideo.mp4 https://youtu.be/pUECdF7KCN4")
         
        
    }
```

When I run the program and press the button linked to the code above, I get this error:

```
    /bin/bash: /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl: Operation not permitted
```

How do I give it permission?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If the goal of the app is to support download of YouTube videos, it probably does not really need elevated privileges. If Youtube-dl requires that, it may not be a great candidate for a native Mac app back-end. A better choice may be to implement its functionality and/or look for alternate APIs that let you do this without elevated priveleges (or python dependency, for that matter).

That said, if you really want to run an external tool with elevated privileges, you'll need to use XPC to create a privileged helper tool and have the user authorize it to run as admin at runtime. This API evolved a bit in the past few OS releases and is, somewhat by design I think, not trivial to implement.

Most sample code out there is in Objective-C, so you'll need to be comfortable using those Objective-C APIs from Swift - or write the elevation code in Objective-C and wrap it in a class you can easily call from Swift. The elevated tool wrapper is launched as an XPCService by launchd, and your app communicates to it through a mach port.

The full code and project set-up is beyond the scope of what will fit in this reply, but here's an example of the setup method as implemented in Objective-C, abbreviated from the EvenBetterAuthorizationSample code (comments and diagnotistic pragmas removed):

```
- (void)connectWithEndpointAndAuthorizationReply:(void(^)(NSXPCListenerEndpoint * endpoint, NSData * authorization))reply
{
    [self.queue addOperationWithBlock:^{

        if (self.helperToolConnection == nil) {
            self.helperToolConnection = [[NSXPCConnection alloc] initWithMachServiceName:kHelperToolMachServiceName options:NSXPCConnectionPrivileged];
            self.helperToolConnection.remoteObjectInterface = [NSXPCInterface interfaceWithProtocol:@protocol(HelperToolProtocol)];
 
            self.helperToolConnection.invalidationHandler = ^{

                self.helperToolConnection.invalidationHandler = nil;
                [self.queue addOperationWithBlock:^{
                    self.helperToolConnection = nil;
                    NSLog(@"connection invalidated");
                }];
            };
            [self.helperToolConnection resume];
        }

        [[self.helperToolConnection remoteObjectProxyWithErrorHandler:^(NSError * proxyError) {
            NSLog(@"connect failed: %@ / %d", [proxyError domain], (int) [proxyError code]);
            reply(nil, nil);
        }] connectWithEndpointReply:^(NSXPCListenerEndpoint *replyEndpoint) {
            reply(replyEndpoint, self.authorization);
        }];
    }];
}
```

And here is the current link to the full project sample:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/samplecode/EvenBetterAuthorizationSample/Introduction/Intro.html

An Apple developer forum thread says this should be possible from Swift:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/99151

Here is another SO thread on the topic:
[Application, Helper Tool Communication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12550730/application-helper-tool-communication/32082886#32082886)